# Error management in grails

Tags: javascript, grails, error-handling

I am quite new to Grails and in an application I need to check dates. In a former Java program I have used two javascript functions with different detail granularity. Both accept dates from 1970-01-01 to 2099-12-31. One demands a correct date and (optionally) time and just tells the user he/she made an erroneous entry:

```
function okdate1(dtstr) {
  var ok = true;
  // First trim off leading and trailing white space
  var trimPattern = /(?:\b(.*)\b)/;
  dtstr = (dtstr.match(trimPattern))[1];
  // Verify that input is within range and correct
  var pat = /^((?:19[7-9][0-9])|(?:20[0-9][0-9]))-((?:(?:0)?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))-((?:(?:0)?[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[01]))(?: ((?:(?:0|1)[0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
  var dtm = dtstr.match(pat);
  if (!dtm) {
    ok = false;
  } else { // Verify that day in in range for the given month
    var days = Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
    // Compensate for leap year
    if ((((dtm[1] % 4) === 0) && !((dtm[1] % 100) === 0)) || ((dtm[1] % 400) === 0)) {
        days[1] = 29;
    }
    if (dtm[3] > days[dtm[2] - 1]) ok = false;
  }
  if (!ok) alert("Enter date and (optionally) time on the form 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'");
  return ok;
}
```

and the other that checks exactly what went wrong by accepting a wider range on the numeric parts of the input string:

```
function okdate2(dtstr) {
  // First trim off leading and trailing white space
  var trimPattern = /(?:\b(.*)\b)/;
  dtstr = (dtstr.match(trimPattern))[1];
  // If nothing then skip the rest
  if (!dtstr) return datetimealert(0);
  // Pattern to recognize any 'dddd-dd-dd[ dd:dd]' pattern
  var pat = /^(?:(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2}))(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}))?$/;
  var dtm = dtstr.match(pat);
  // If this is does not follow the pattern: get out
  if (!dtm) return datetimealert(0);
  // convert each group to a number
  // if no time notation the corresponding groups become NaN
  for (var i = 1; i < dtm.length; i++) {
    dtm[i] = Number(dtm[i]);
  }
  // Check for correct year interval
  if (dtm[1] < 1970 || dtm[1] > 2099) return datetimealert(1);

  // Check for correct month notation
  if (dtm[2] < 1 || dtm[2] > 12) return datetimealert(2);

  // Array with correct numer of days for each month
  var mdays = Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
  // Compensate for leap year
  if ((((dtm[1] % 4) === 0) && !((dtm[1] % 100) === 0)) || ((dtm[1] % 400) === 0)) {
    mdays[1] = 29;
  }
  // Check the day for the given month
  if (dtm[3] < 1 || mdays[dtm[2] - 1] < dtm[3]) return datetimealert(3);

  // If only date was given and no time, we are OK
  if (isNaN(dtm[4]) && isNaN(dtm[5])) return true;

  // This can not happen according to pattern, but ...
  if (isNaN(dtm[4]) || isNaN(dtm[5])) return datetimealert(4);

  // check given hour
  if (dtm[4] > 23) return datetimealert(5);

  // Check given minutes
  if (dtm[5] > 59) return datetimealert(6);

  // If no error
  return true;
}
```

where the function datetimealert puts out an alert with a (hopefully) good error message and returns false. The 'trimpattern' in both function strip leading and trailing whitespace.

I used them in my forms where I made calls to them in an "onsubmit" function. My objective here is not to discuss the two functions but comments on them are, of course, welcome.

In my Grails application I use jQuery datepicker extended with Trent Richardsons jQuery timepicker addon, so I get a text string as a result. I call the datetimepicker in a form:

```
    <form ...
      <dl ...
        <dt>Start date <span class="required-indicator">*</span></dt>
        <dd>
          <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: todoInstance, field: 'startdate', 'error')} required">
            <g:textField name="startdate" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"
                 value="${formatDate(format:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',date:todoInstance?.startad)}" required="" />
          </div>
        </dd>
        ...
```

For all the other 'required' fields I get a little 'tooltip'-like message telling me to
enter a value into the field.

Now, I want to use my two datetime javascript in my grails application but I don't want alert boxes popping up, I want to use them in the static-constraints section in the domain classes and get my messages in the same manner as for the other fields. How do I integrate them into the error management system i grails?

Comment: todoInstance?.startad in the last code block should be todoInstance?.startdate

Answer (score 1):

This error messages are provided by the [validation API](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html). To inplement your own customized validations you can use the constraint [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html).

<strike>But I'm assuming that you already declared your field as `java.util.Date` in the domain class, so you need a Date object in the validator. By default, Grails handle dates with `g:datePicker`, that will split the date in day, month and year fields.</strike>

To bind a single String with some format to a date object, you can register a custom Date Property Editor, like [this example](http://ishanf.tumblr.com/post/434379583/custom-property-editor-for-grails).

The Grails validation API is for server side validation. In your case one option is the [JQuery Validation UI Plugin](http://limcheekin.github.com/jquery-validation-ui/docs/guide/index.html), that provides client side validation through JQuery. The plugin supports all standard constraints and you can create your own validations (like your date validations), checkout the [extensibility docs session](http://limcheekin.github.com/jquery-validation-ui/docs/guide/usage.html).

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem. I handle conversions. The problem is to integrate my error handling into the Grails error management system.

Comment: You mean instead of alert, your javascript function show the error div like other grails validations?

Comment: Exactly. I want to replace the alerts with calls to produce such error messages and understand how to integrate them into my application and make use of the functions in the validation infrastructure.